# Troubleshooting SAML 2.0 federation with Office 365

Tags: java, azure, single-sign-on, office365, saml-2.0

I am using password synchronization together with the Azure AD Connect tool. I have enabled `SAML 2.0` federation with Office 365 domain(Secondary).

When I am trying to login to the test user account, I am getting "**We don't recognize this user ID or password**" error. If I reset password of test user account from the Office 365 admin panel, test user is able to login from the Single sign On page. When next sync happens with Azure Active Directory, I am getting same issue again.

Please help me out.